# Lottery Probability Question: probability of exactly $x$ matching numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question follows:

"In a lottery game $6$ balls are drawn randomly from $49$ balls. If you pick $6$ different numbers:

i) What is the probability that your numbers match those drawn?

ii) What is the probability that exactly $x$ of the numbers you choose match?"

So I've done part (i) and got $$\frac{1}{\binom{49}{6}}$$ which is roughly $7.2E-10$, but I'm not sure on how to approach (ii).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to the first question is correct.

**Hint:**  If you match exactly $x$ of the $6$ selected numbers, you must also choose $6 - x$ of the remaining $49 - 6 = 43$ numbers.

Comment: Alright got the answer as (6 C x)*(43 C 6-x)/(49 C 6). Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is correct.